# sql select statement view

Tags: sql

Today i made a post about a issue i was having with sql, with the help of some people over there i figured out how my query had to be.

Now i have a different question, the result of my previous query:

```
select
count(case when Job = 'Garbageman' then 1 end) as GarbageCount,
count(case when Job = 'Delivery' then 1 end) as DeliveryCount
      from Job
```

are:

```
GarbageCount:   DelivryCount:
4               5
```

What i am trying to achieve is the following:

```
Job:            Count:
Garbage         4
Delivery        5
```

My table is the following:

```
User:    Job:
Mark     Garbageman
Dirk     Garbageman
Henk     Garbageman
Steven   Garbageman
Mark     Delivery
Dirk     Delivery
Henk     Delivery
Steven   Delivery
Stevens  Delivery
```

Anyone know how my sql query has to look like?

Comment: `select count(job) ... group by job`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Group by` is all you're looking for:

```
select job, count(*)
from yourtable
group by job
```

Comment: The results are correct but I think a column name should be given for count to give more specific answer.  i.e  count(*) as [Count] .